# Run time Error 1004 Application defined/object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm generating unique keys for invoice by using the below code and im getting **Run time Error 1004 Application defined or object defined error** in line

```
cell.Value = CStr(d & Mx)
```

Why I'm getting it?

```
Private Sub Key_Gen()

Dim WIP_rng As Range
Dim d As String, c As Long, r As Long, s As Integer, p As Integer


Set WIP_rng = Range("WIP[Key]")

Mx = WorksheetFunction.Max(keynum)
c = 1
p = 0
    For Each col In WIP_rng
    r = col.Row
        If col.Value = "" And Cells(r, 3).Value <> "" And Cells(r, 4).Value <> "" And Cells(r, 5).Value <> "" And Cells(r, 6).Value <> "" And Cells(r, 7).Value <> "" Then
            s = Val(Len(Trim(Mx)))
            Debug.Print s
            t = 5
            p = t - s
            Debug.Print p
               If p = 1 Then
               p = "0"
               ElseIf p = 2 Then
                p = "00"
               ElseIf p = 3 Then
                p = "000"
               ElseIf p = 4 Then
                p = "0000"
                ElseIf p = 0 Then
                p = ""
               End If
                Mx = CStr(Mx + c)
                d = CStr("MG" & p)
                d = d & Mx
                col.Value = d
        c = c + 1
        End If
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know? What are the values d and Mx?

Comment: d will be in pattern "MG000" and Mx will be Long. Invoice no will be like MG00981

Comment: There's a lot of undeclared variables in your code.  I've not seen a range referenced as `"WIP[Key]"` before - is that valid?  What is the value of `Num_Key`?  `c`, `r`, `l` and `s` should be `Long` I take it?

Comment: I didn't ask what they will be, but what they ARE. When it errors what are their values?

Comment: Please refer the attached updated code..

Comment: @SJR during error d = MG00 and MX 981

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes

Comment: Not sure. Inside your Select Case try using a different string variable than l which you have previously used as an integer.

Comment: I would recommend another name for a `cell` variable.. if certain references are added it can be confused with `Word` object `Cell` which is an object of `Word` `Table` cell.

Comment: Sry tired different name already and still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Write `Option Explicit` on top.
Then declare all the variables.

Eg. `Dim d as String`. It would work.

Or quick and dirty:

```
cell.Value = CStr(d) & CStr(Mx)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error :(
Thank you for your help :P

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Try changing the name of `cell As Range` to something like `myCell As Range`. Because `cell` is an object in VBA so you can't use that name.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Then I don't know either.